# d3-request incorrectly assembling a path and using wrong host

Tags: node.js, d3.js, npm, d3-request

I'm running a server via `npm start` on `10.0.1.18:3000`.
I'm doing:

```
import * as request from 'd3-request';
const myPath = './data/my_file.json';
request.json(myPath, (error,data)=>console.log(error,data));
```

This is failing, with an error:
`"Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from //localhost:80./data/my_file.json`"

It seems like there are two problems:

- It's looking for `localhost:80` instead of `10.0.1.18:3000`
- It's just concatenating the path, including leading "." instead of interpreting it correctly.

Comment: This is a confusing question. You're defining `myPath` but passing `path` to `request.json()`. Is that a typo? This is running in the browser -- how is it supposed to know what port and ip address your server is running on if you just hand it a relative path? Also, you don't need the `.` before the path.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. fixed.
That's my question I suppose. if I don't tell it the server and port, it uses localhost:80. How do I properly construct the right path?

Comment: Normally you would just have `const host = 'http://10.0.1.18:3000'` and then `request.json(host + myPath)` or even `const url = 'http://10.0.1.18:3000/data/my_file.json'` and then `request.json(url)`. Of course if the file is on the same server as the d3 page, you would just load it directly rather than over http.

Comment: Wow, I have just run into this as well - in my case I was passing 'path/to/my/file.csv', pretty shocked to see it request it from localhost with no port.